# concat_axis in the merge function of Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras

In keras, we can use merge to concatenate two layers. There is a parameter `concat_axis`. Looks like the default value for this parameter is `-1`, and quite some code setup it as `1`. What do they mean, `concat_axis=1 and concat_axis=-1`, respectively. I could not find the explanation in Keras document. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`concat_axis` means the axis/dimension to concatenate.
if your input tensor has shape `(samples, channels, rows, cols)`,
set `concat_axis` to `1` to concatenate per feature map (`channels axis`).